# Have you found any sites which copy SO's scoring system

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm interested to know how many sites people have found since  SO started, which have in some way copied the voting system?

Do you think that a voting system like this is only likely to work in a situation like a programming Q/A site where people tend to take pride in being able to gain reputation for their programming knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the clones listed here:

> [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones)

Comment: Ah cheers for that. I notice that most of them are programming related (which makes sense I guess).

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think that a voting system like this is only likely to work in a situation like a programming Q/A site where people tend to take pride in being able to gain reputation for their programming knowledge?

Based on sites like ServerFault, SuperUser, and even Meta itself, I think that will dispel any idea that the voting system and reputation in general is only going to work on Programming Q&A.

Reputation is your score just like on any video game. Give anybody a task and attach a score to it "carrot on a stick" and you'd be surprised how much activity you can get.

Comment: @TheTXI Thanks for your answer. Do you think it's purely the rep that people can earn then, or does getting increased privileges also count?

Comment: mdresser: Privileges is definitely part of it. I worked like a dog to get up to 10k rep on StackOverflow but after I got there I sort of lost a lot of reason to keep answering there. I know some others sort of feel the same, but there is still a lot of fun in answering questions as well just for the heck of it.